# Javascript button click function isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, xml

So I have an XML that is holds 4 pictures and my JS is suppose to pull the images inside the XML and display them after I click the button. But when I run my program, the button shows up and it is clickable. But when I click the button, the  doesn't show up and neither do the pictures inside it even though im calling it in the click function. Does anyone know why?

```
var xml;
var raceName;
var raceSrc;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var xmlDoc = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Lab8XML.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: null
    });
    $(document.getElementById("button")).click(function(){
        xml = $(xmlDoc.responseXML);
        getRandomRace();
        $("<img src='" + raceSrc + "' alt='" + raceName + "' />").appendTo("#raceArea");
        $("#raceArea > h2").text(raceName);
        setInterval(displayNewRace, 5000);
    });
});

function displayNewRace() {
    $("#raceArea").fadeOut("slow");
    setTimeout(changeRace, 500);
    $("#raceArea").fadeIn("slow");
}

function changeRace() {
    getRandomRace();
    $("img").attr("src", raceSrc);
    $("img").attr("alt", raceName);
    $("#raceArea > h2").text(raceName);
}

//Math.random returns a number between 0 and .9999
//Math.floor chops off the decimal place to make an int
function randomInt(minInt, maxInt) {
    return Math.floor(minInt + Math.random() * (maxInt - minInt +1));
}

function getRandomRace() {
    //call randomInt(minInt = 0, maxInt = array length - 1)
    var $rand = randomInt(0, xml.find("race").length - 1); 
    //Pick out a random pokemon
    var $randomRace = $(xml.find("race")[$rand]);
    //Set the name and source to access them later
    raceName = $randomRace.children("name").text();
    raceSrc = $randomRace.children("img").attr("src");
}
```

Comment: What is `$(document.getElementById("button"))` ?

Comment: You are binding a click event to an element before it exists. put the handler binding into the `$(document).ready` block.

Comment: Why are you doing `$(document.getElementById("button"))`?

Comment: @jbabey: It is, the indentation is just a bit off.

Comment: Your amajaxing is completely off. Please look at real examples. You need to add a success function where your weird docuemnt.getelementbyid is now

Comment: What happens if you click the button before the XML is loaded? You should have a success callback function in your AJAX call.  Then bind the click after the XML has successfully loaded. I would recommend hiding the button until then too.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's wrong with your code is that you're defining a local variable `xml` instead of a global variable so that the function you're calling (`getRandomRace`) can't access that variable.


Instead of `var xml = ...` inside your click function, do `window.xml = ...`, or even better, make xml a parameter of the `getRandomRace` function so that it can access it.

Good luck!